# show the error in return type of NSObject

Tags: ios, swift

I made a `NSObject` to parse the value for `collectionView`. It is going to build fail because it show the error in retype. I think that I have the problem to write code. But I am not realize where is my mistake please try to help me.

```
import UIKit

import Foundation

class AppCategory: NSObject {

    var tShirtImageOb: String?
    var tShirtLabelOb: String?
    var tShirtPrizeOb: NSNumber?


    static func sampleAppCategories() -> [AppCategory] {

        var bestNewAppsCategoryArray = [AppCategory]()

        let bestNewAppsCategory = AppCategory()
        bestNewAppsCategory.tShirtImageOb = "tShirt"
        bestNewAppsCategory.tShirtLabelOb = "Best New Apps"
        bestNewAppsCategory.tShirtPrizeOb = NSNumber(value: 599.0 as Float)
        bestNewAppsCategoryArray.append(bestNewAppsCategory)



        var bestNewGamesCategoryArray = [AppCategory]()

        let bestNewGamesCategory = AppCategory()
        bestNewGamesCategory.tShirtImageOb = "tShirt"
        bestNewGamesCategory.tShirtLabelOb = "Best New Apps"
        bestNewGamesCategory.tShirtPrizeOb = NSNumber(value: 599.0 as Float)
        bestNewGamesCategoryArray.append(bestNewGamesCategory)


        // show the error in down line
        return [bestNewAppsCategoryArray, bestNewGamesCategoryArray]


    }
}
```

Comment: You are actually returning a `[[AppCategory]]` but you declared it to return `[AppCategory]`. Decide which one is correct and change the code accordingly.

Comment: you are returned the array not [[AppCategory]]

Comment: @Azmal Tech you are returning multiple arrays not array of object type AppCategory no need to create two different array just create two different object and append in array both the objects,and return .

Comment: @TusharSharma thank you

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return an array of your `AppCategory` object with all new game and new apps categories, append them together in your return line.

So change this line

```
return [bestNewAppsCategoryArray, bestNewGamesCategoryArray]
```

Into

```
return bestNewAppsCategoryArray + bestNewGamesCategoryArray
```

Comment: can you me help to answer this question. i want to detect one button in tableview cell by click on button. here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970198/how-to-detect-one-button-in-tableview-cell?noredirect=1#comment84948065_48970198